# Use Ajax or Attributes for Images

Tags: jquery

What is better for dynamically loading images- using an ajax function or changing the image's src attribute to the desired link?
Please supply a snippet of code with your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your definition of "better," but since JavaScript really doesn't deal well with binary streams, I'd recommend the "changing the image's `src` attribute" option.

```
var mySource = '/path/to/image.jpg';

var img = new Image();
img.src = mySource;

// or

$('#someImageId').attr('src', mySource);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Binary streams yeah I noticed that lol.